# Draw a Polygon with Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, drawable, polygon, shapes

I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this with Xamarin.Forms.

[image]

I already can seprate my layout like this but i wonder how can i do to draw a Polygon ? Or maybe is there an other way to achieve this ? A better way like a drawable ? But it need to be the same on every device ...

```cs
// Relative Layouts
this.contentLayout = new RelativeLayout();
this.topLayout = new RelativeLayout();
this.bottomLayout = new RelativeLayout();

//topLayout.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00162E");
//bottomLayout.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");

// Top and Bottom Layouts
this.contentLayout.Children.Add(
    topLayout,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return 0; }),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return 0; }),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return (parent.Height/2.5); })
);
this.contentLayout.Children.Add(
    bottomLayout,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return 0; }),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return this.topLayout.Height; }),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return (parent.Height / 1.5); })
);

// Inside Top Layout
// ??? Draw Polygon

// Inside Bottom Layout
```

Thanks everybody !

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [NControl](https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl). I haven't used it myself yet, but you should be able to achieve the look and feel you're looking for with it.

It's a wrapper built around [NGraphics](https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics) that supports many shapes, including paths.